# VMWare Workstation 8 can't find the headers directory

Tags: 13.04, vmware

I'm having an issue with VMware Workstation 8.

I installed it but when i run it, it shows this window:

[image]

But, when I press on "Browse", this window comes up

[image]

Even if I select the `linux-headers-3.8.0-31-generic` folder, it says that it can't find the C headers for that kernel. Why?

*P.S. I already tried `sudo apt-get install linux-headers-3.8.0-31-generic` and the terminal says that the kernel is up to date.*